# How to prevent navbar overlapping content in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to find a solution to my navbar overlapping my page content. Here is my code:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-control-title="List" id="pg-lst">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a data-role="button" href="#pg-hm" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left"> </a>
            <h3> Establishments </h3>
            <div id="lst-navbar" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#pg-fllwng" data-transition="none"> Following </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#pg-mp" data-transition="fade"> Map </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">                
            <div id="frm-srch" class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-mini="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder=""></ul>                        
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a id="btn-cancel-search" href="#"> Cancel </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="lst-estblshmnt" data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="false" ></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the image below you will see that the navbar overlaps the listview filter.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: can you add a fiddle ? need to see your css as well

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with using `data-position:fixed` in combination with a header that stretches over 1.1em in height.

By default `.ui-content` has a padding of `1em`, you will need to adjust that and give it more in `padding-top` property to avoid overlapping of your content.

You could try

```
.ui-content {
  padding-top:2em
}
```

... and see how that goes. You'll probably have to adjust it a little to suit your needs though.

---

EDIT:

Just created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLWtdK6zj65RgUzgrj22?p=preview) to test it out, and there don't seem to be an issue there with jQuery Mobile's standard CSS. So the issue is probably in your own CSS.